# PHP simplexml  get image display

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an xml that looks something like this:

```
<gallery server="5"> 
    <image path="http://i.imgur.com/8n5MB.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://i.imgur.com/TIXL2.jpg"/>
</gallery>
```

I'm trying to get the images to display in one page using PHP. This is what I have:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('./images.xml');

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . "<br />";
  }
```

My problem is that this only outputs the following

```
gallery
image
image
image
```

I can't find any information on how to read the information of the tag itself, any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: I'm just curious as to whether or not you tried google.

Comment: The image path is an attribute.

Comment: need to check the manual before posting man, [Check Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php#refsect1-simplexmlelement.attributes-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this instead:

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $child)
{
    echo '<img src="' . $child['path'] . '" alt="gallery image" />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks This works great, i couldn't find it mostly cause i didn't know what it was called, I'm new to xml and php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XPath](http://php.net/simplexml.xpath) to select the elements, then grab the `path` attribute from the element's list of attributes, like this:

```
foreach( $xml->xpath('//image') as $image)
{
    $attributes = $image->attributes();
    echo $attributes['path'] . "<br />";
}
```

So this loop will only loop over the `<image>` tags. For every `<image>` tag, it grabs that tag's attributes and prints out the `path` attribute.

Comment: Or you can just go straigth for the variable like `$xml -> children() -> attributes` :)

Comment: `children()` will be an array of SimpleXML elements - I don't think that will work.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't testing, just fast writing the idea. That's why I didn't post it as an answer m8 :)